# Undefined method error.What should I do?

Tags: ruby

I am practicing to code in Ruby and when I type the following code,I get the following error.In this case,what should I do?

The code is here:

```
class RandomSequence

def initialize(limit,num)
@limit,@num=limit,num
end

def each
@num.times {yield(rand*@limit).floor}
end
end

i=-1

RandomSequence.new(10,4).each do |num|
i=num if i<num
end
```

http://ideone.com/bSkAXN

the error message I get is:

```
prog.rb:8:in block in each: undefined method floor for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from prog.rb:8:in times
    from prog.rb:8:in each
    from prog.rb:14:in <main>
```

Comment: put the code in question itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parentheses:

```
    @num.times {yield((rand*@limit).floor)}
```

Without the extra parentheses, `yield(rand*@limit)` returns `nil`, and you get a `NoMethodError` for calling `nil.floor`.